# Using Android MediaPlayer with C#Shell

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer

I'm attempting to use the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class using [c#shell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=animaonline.cshell.free)

But it doesn't seem to play the specified stream and I'm not getting any error messages.

Here is my code:

```
using Android.Media;
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://domain.com/file.mp3");
var mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.SetDataSource(cs.Context, uri);
mp.Start();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure C#Shell has wrappers around the internal parts of Android? I don't think C#Shell is the same as `monodroid`.

Comment: Yes it seems so, all of Android api is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call Prepare() before you Start() the playback